# CSS Create a border on current page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to copy a Sit the Test website, and got stuck in the border on the current page.
What I wanted is to make a border in Build test so it looks like a current page. 
I have this HTML.

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #D9E0E6;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #323b44;
}

.web-logo img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 15px 30px 15px 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: catamaran, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li a.current {
  /* I'm trying to make a border here on the current page which is the Build Test*/
  border: 3px solid #80dbb8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #80dbb8;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  border: 3px solid #80dbb8;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

````html
```
<header>
  <div class="web-logo"><img src="img/logo-bd2b73d4287cc1b0b5d0562cbf409217.png" alt="Site the Test Logo"></div>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current" id="current">Build Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Browse Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
````

does anyone can help?
These are for the design only I'm not working yet with the page transition.

Comment: Happy to help you write up some styles but I can't picture what you want help with. What are you struggling with please?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this "*make a border in Build test so it looks like a current page*" Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ohw, i did it. Its just, my live server in VScode didn't refresh. I'm so sorry.